# Understanding the Correspondence of Sections to Right and Left Invariant Vector Fields in Ping Xu's 'Momentum Maps and Morita Equivalence

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, vector-fields, symplectic-geometry

I want to understand this passage on the articule: *Ping Xu. "Momentum Maps and Morita Equivalence".*

**By $A → P$ we denote the Lie algebroid of $Γ\rightrightarrows P$, where the anchor map is denoted by
$a : A → TP$. For any $ξ ∈ Γ(A)$, by $\overrightarrow{\xi}$ and $\overleftarrow{\xi}$ we denote its corresponding right-and left-invariant
vector fields on Γ respectively.**

why does every section $ξ ∈ Γ(A)$ have a vector field on $Γ$ and why do we have two, a right invariant and a lerf invariant vector fields? Thank you!